# `Object.entries().map()` don't preserve types on typescript. How can I improve my interface for it to work? or workaround?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have this interface that i am working with:

```
export interface NPMPackage {
  name: string;
  description: string;
  'dist-tags': {
    [tag: string]: string;
  };
  versions: {
    [version: string]: {
      name: string;
      version: string;
      dependencies?: {
        [packageName: string]: string;
      };
    };
  };
}
```

and this is my code:

```
let dependencies =  npmPackage.versions[version].dependencies;
dependencies = Object.entries(dependencies).map( ([name, version]) => ({
    name,
    version: version.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, ''),
}));
```

that returns these errors:

> Type '{ name: string; version: string; }[]' is not assignable to type
> '{ [packageName: string]: string; }'.   Index signature is missing in
> type '{ name: string; version: string; }[]'.
>
> No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 2, '(o: { [s: string]:
> string; } | ArrayLike): [string, string][]', gave the
> following error.
> Argument of type '{ [packageName: string]: string; } | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ [s: string]: string; } |
> ArrayLike'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{ [s: string]: string; } | ArrayLike'.   Overload 2 of 2, '(o: {}): [string,
> any][]', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '{ [packageName: string]: string; } | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '{}'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{}'.

without the `dependencies` function it works with no errors.

if i add `dependencies:any` and change the `versions` variable without manipulating it like this:

```
    let dependencies =  npmPackage.versions[version].dependencies;
    // lets make it pretty. 
    dependencies = Object.entries(dependencies).map( ([name, version]) => ({
        name,
        version,
    }));
```

it works.

basically what i am trying to do is to add the dependencies method to change the structure of my object. the structure of the objects is passed to the new variable `dependencies`. what is the proper solution for these cases with typescript? is that considered a good practice when typehinting?

The api returns the data as described, but i want to send it with a different structure for the react frontend app.

also. the thing that i do not understand is - that the variable is a string as stated in the interface, so why doesn't it work?

[reproducible](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAgJYDs4hgMwIYGMQIByACgLLF4DW2A5gQN7AIIrYC2IAXAgM5wyoaAbiYIAJiB64BEOEigpufASmGiA5GKR8AtHFo913Rs2YBtfTSX9BAXWsq1zAL4jmANww95KHsdHmnjDeCg52-qamrBxhqm6RCEEhirw2cQGmEhAgKBIouEiSAPwRCebRXKmO9lWC8ZGuGY0uIs7AwPwAngiMGQD0fQi4CnwsEGwUuNR03CTkVLQEALwI2ADu2EiINFBwABT9gwCQAAYAFnBwEH4DMCA02l0AdCjjAFY8T7A0fXd4cCcADSmAA8SxWXQQMAArigUIIEHAztoEJhYIizgRYEgHqwADYIKDQq7Ep4IQ4IACUTw+Cj2lPqQxGiFeEwWMyIZEm02WPXJZWYACIKoLOIK-rg4ILARlIoKJFIZHIFKKEIKAEogf7IHirBAAKWw7mwAGVpEhZAg8UgAEYwbAwbpomAIG3QpB4rSqBDQngYZBoDA4fCfaWy0zyx56AyqkwCuV47DoPiqwUARgA7E8AAxPABMYfjcpQ4Cl3HTAA4czmdNg8RAztgdCAxAA2XDZgCcacwIB0eezebT2Yz2bThaLQvA2QEHDQddTuaXzcgGCQc-0eObbY73d7-cHw9H45lk6FdYb2FTaary4vje37a7Pb7A6HI7HgvDLlPAsFSR8HhY2-BJhXYEBUwlKVgRAuUAJVcs01bJ40wAZhzCdJ3TZC0Iw0ozwjLIcjyApJGAgj40FPEoCgP1mxQdwkEwTpUwAPTTFCMN-CjQKgG03hASVax4bwaBQNiABZOJPWCz0FCAYCgCA9E6bIgPLdiAFYnmQgtZLKNoCMMgVjJcdpIgGBAAEkEAUkBGKJHg8W6X0WwQThsBQbpMTuBA3l9RBnWQRA4CgKFYVWXIoUkKA8U8K0kwwMkMmNF0iNyHJSL8TzuhWVluUWJ54N8Mx1CQlD0OzdRbCedKSMKHhGUstZYEoXU1i2M4iRCzEmTYDc3OtEsMjqzKGoQFYAHl+MEuAnhyGxJD2Ub8ga6k2GwCA9gQPYzAqYFitsSkJoAPh2uMyn2kDiu4hJLOK7hiqeO4IETfA9j6MwADIAB0+h+n6AGJAQAanpAASAA-ABSVjIfUUUACoihBE76GcWw+hoYF1HUSkmkpBl2mJik7jgaEYBQaLPj4JNfT2Ads2pWkUD2egWHAg6vB8YEVqyhBnCJ5whiTXAzh2jBFJgY6LoQSyyYpqmSzAfZJdgIWScs6dZrcu4eGhPFEBag2xESAgkRROBVKxF1YAkGBgU803ivazrut4To2BtWLPnaSzIkYf2BUDwYCIqctqNovsckY5jpXJIPJwetUOI47NBQT0OTJgxOEhDijw7VPiBKE7ARJxcSc6zpPudCNUpNTr9c4aKui3zgieHAhAfJAJ4++AZvTDaXPnCAA)

Comment: The problem is that `Object.entries`, same as `Object.keys` and `Object.values` don't preserve types.

Comment: @VojtěchStrnad I figured that the type isn't matching. My question is what can i do with data that i want to change its structure and how. what is the common practice? I tried changing the interface a few times but wasn't managed to create something that would work with the current.

Comment: You can't really mutate the type of a variable in TypeScript.  You either need to widen the type to something that accommodates both such as a union like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nd4ZdN), or just use two different variables like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mZanaN).  But I'd really like to see a [mcve] that demonstrates what you're doing; you say "change the `versions` variable without manipulating it like this", but you're not modifying the `versions` property (it's not a variable) at all; `map()` doesn't mutate the passed-in array... so I'm confused.

Comment: Is the big problem that `dependencies` is optional?  You need to check or assert that it's not `undefined` before passing it to `Object.entries()`.

Comment: Hi @jcalz. im so happy you commented here, i actually saw a few of your comments around that subject :) I created a reproducible, but wanst able to make it run, im not sure why (im new to typescript) so please take a look on it (edited in main post)

Comment: Wait, if that code is a [mcve] of your problem, then your question post isn't really relevant anymore?  The code has four compiler errors and a runtime error, none of which seem to be what you're asking about.  You have `return` statements that are not in the body of a function, which you or someone should fix before anyone can look at it.  I'm not really able to do that myself, though, since the whole point is to reproduce your original problem, and you're the only one who can verify that this has occurred... 

Comment: no it runs on my server, i just coulnd get it working here. giveme a few seconds. ill try agiain i a minute.

Comment: @jcalz i managed to minimize the errors to 2. just dont get why the types do not sync here and on my server it runs fine :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to change the structure of my object. The structure of the objects is passed to the new variable `dependencies`.

No, it's not. You're assigning it to the *old* variable `dependencies`, which is inferred to have the old structure as its type.

> what is the proper solution for these cases with typescript?

Use two different variables for different objects with different structures. One is a object mapping strings to strings, the other is an array of objects. So write

```
const dependenciesObj = npmPackage.versions[version].dependencies;
// lets make it pretty. 
const dependenciesArr = Object.entries(dependencies).map( ([name, version]) => ({
    name,
    version,
}));
```